# Can I take a derivative of any complex function so long as I treat the complex numbers as matrices?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

Complex numbers can be represented as matrices, for example

$$
a+bi \leftrightarrow \pmatrix{a &b\\-b&a}
$$
Only some functions of a complex variable have a derivative that is a complex number (those which are holomorphic). However, I can take derivatives of all smooth maps from matrices to matrices, even those that correspond to functions that are not holomorphic. What gives?

Comment: Only some functions of a complex variable have a derivative that is a complex number, yes, and only some matrices represent complex numbers. When you take the derivative of a smooth map from matrices to matrices that does not correspond to a holomorphic function, you get a matrix that does not represent a complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of what the derivative is: A linear approximation to the function at a point.

Let's think about the complex plane as a 2-dimensional real plane, and take a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$. Its derivative at, say, the origin is an $\Bbb R$-linear transformation $f'_{(0,0)}:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(x,y)\approx f(0,0)+f_{(0,0)}'(x,y)$ (with some formal requirements on $\approx$). Any linear transformation of the plane can appear as the derivative; any $2\times2$ real matrix.

Now think about the same function as $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. This time the derivative at $0$ is a $\Bbb C$-linear transformation $f_0':\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ such that $f(z)\approx f(0)+f'_0(z)$. The available linear transformations here are only scalings (equally much in all directions) and rotations (i.e. multiplication by a complex number). No mirroring, no skew transformations, and so on. It's just more restrictive.

Comment: Isn't there a factor missing next to $f'$ in both Taylor approximations?

Comment: @ILikeSerena First off, those are not Taylor approximations, they are the definition of the derivative (along with rigourously constraining $\approx$, of course). Second, no. That's what it's supposed to be.